# Iterating over Ebay listings with bs4

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble with a for loop in bs4, see code below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import request

html = urlopen('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=manga&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

#soldItem = soup.find_all('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags')
#salePrice = soup.find_all('span', class_='POSITIVE')

itemContainer = soup.find('ul', class_='srp-results srp-list clearfix')

for x in itemContainer.findAll('li'):
    #item = x.get_text()
    item = itemContainer.findAll('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').get_text()
    sale = itemContainer.findAll('span', class_='POSITIVE').get_text()
    data = {item:sale}
    print(data)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I want to be able to iterate over every single listing from ebay in page 1 and get the name item and sale price. I've tried several ways but this error is persistent. I've gotten to the point where this errors does not appear anymore, but my variable iterates over the first line 50 times.

Any ideas on how to generate the data in the following format {item name:sale price}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what the error message says - you're using `findAll` when you should be using `find`. Also, you're finding all of the h3's and spans in the itemContainer instead of each item (`x`) in the container.

Try replacing

```
item = itemContainer.findAll('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').get_text()
sale = itemContainer.findAll('span', class_='POSITIVE').get_text()
```

with

```
item = x.find('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').get_text()
sale = x.find('span', class_='POSITIVE').get_text()
```

Edit:

One more thing: when you do `for x in itemContainer.findAll('li')`, you're finding *all* of the li's in the itemContainer. It just so happens that there are  more than just items for sale in that list, so it finds some that don't have an h3 with a nested span or text. So that's why it fails. Narrowing down the search with `itemContainer.findAll('li', class_='s-item')` does the trick.

Here is what the complete code should be now:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = urlopen('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=manga&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

#soldItem = soup.find_all('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags')
#salePrice = soup.find_all('span', class_='POSITIVE')

itemContainer = soup.find('ul', class_='srp-results srp-list clearfix')

for x in itemContainer.find_all('li', class_='s-item'):
    item = x.find('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').get_text()
    sale = x.find('span', class_='POSITIVE').get_text()
    data = {item:sale}
    print(data)
```

Note that I also changed `findAll` to `find_all`, which is just another name for the function that more closely follows pep8 naming conventions. The same could be applied in renaming `itemContainer` to `item_container`, etc, but it's not totally necessary.

Comment: right, but then i get this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Ok. It's been a while since I used bs4. Time to put my google-fu to work! I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Finally got it. When it looks for `li`s, it's finding all of them. There are more than just the ones that are items for sale, so narrowing that down with a `class_ = 's-item'` does the trick. I will edit my answer.

Comment: just ran the code and it works ! thank you so much, i'm going to have to look through your answer to see what i was doing wrong. I was getting stuck because the get_text() method wouldn't return my items back correctly. So, I assume that by setting find_all and the beginning of the loop it will iterate over every item and inside the look I have to utilize find() and get_text()

Comment: thanks for you help ! did you use any specific sources to help you understand/find the answer or just years of practice

Comment: I have done some (but not much) with bs4 before, so I knew the basics (for example, I could understand as I was reading what your code was meant to do. It took some looking to figure out why It didn't do what it was supposed to though). Just search google for "beautiful soup python tutorial" and you should find relevent results. I found this article especially helpful though: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/